# Clone a response before modifying its payload?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Suppose we're implementing a response interceptor in an Angular 4 `HttpClient` based app:

```
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (!(event instanceof HttpResponse))
                return event;

            // Modify event.body somehow like: event.body.items = { ... }; - do we need to do event.clone() before?
        });
    }
}
```

We know that if we were implementing a request interceptor, we have to `clone()` the `req` to maintain its immutability.

But do we need to `clone()` the response before modifying its payload exposed via the `body` property?

Comment: Try it and see? Or do the research: [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#immutability) mention immutability for both requests and responses; and [`HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) exposes everything read-only via get accessors and provides the same `.clone` method.

Comment: This [Post](https://netbasal.com/a-taste-from-the-new-angular-http-client-38fcdc6b359b) has a great explanation on how you should use the interceptors. Take a peek, you're probably find it useful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: What difference are we supposed to observe when response hasn't been cloned in case it's needed to? As for docs, yes, they mention immutability of response, but the rest of the section you provided talks on `Request` only. So they don't clearly say if we need to clone responses.

Comment: @Mihailo: Yes, this seems to be the top post on the topic, but it unfortunately doesn't answer the question if we need to clone responses.

Comment: You need to because *otherwise you can't change the body* - see [the implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L256), it's `readonly`, you can't assign to it. Had you tried it, `tsc` would have told you it wasn't permitted.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - you can replace the entire response if you wish within an interceptor, so the interceptor is not immutable, even for read-only members.

Comment: @Fenton I didn't say the interceptor was immutable. I said the *response object* is immutable. Replacing it entirely *wouldn't* be mutating it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You don't have to assign to `body` itself to change the payload; you can just do something like `event.body.items = { ... };`. So you even might not discover that `body` is read-only.

Comment: Eager to hear the downvoter.

Answer (score -1):

Response interceptors are [officially allowed](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to *either* modify the response object, or create an entirely new one.

> Interceptors exist to examine and mutate outgoing requests and incoming responses.

and

> An interceptor may choose to transform the response event stream as well, by applying additional Rx operators on the stream returned by next.handle().

So the answer to your question is that you are not required to leave the response untouched. This means you are in that wonderful space in programming where you can decide whether to write an interceptor that does or doesn't mutate the response.

If you wish to change a read-only property, you'll have to create a new response, rather than change the one you have.

Comment: That's the AngularJS documentation, not Angular's.

Comment: *"transform the response event stream"* does not necessarily imply mutating an individual response object in that stream, though. It's clear from the `HttpResponse`'s read-only API that it shouldn't be mutated, IMO.

Comment: If we can freely mutate the response, then do you know why [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#immutability) say the following: `However, it may be surprising to learn that the HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes **are largely immutable**.` What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Angular is written in TypeScript, but you can consume it from JavaScript. Although a compiler may prevent you from writing to the `body` property, you can dodge that with `let x: any = response; x.body = 'new';` if you wish. Then it becomes a question of whether there is anything to actively prevent this in the JavaScript. The apparant read-only nature of the interface does not make the members immutable.

Comment: I think that discussing that `body` is a read-only property and ways to modify it has nothing to do with my question. Modifying the `Request` is a logical error, though nothing on the compiler side prevents you from doing it. But my question is whether modifying the `Response` contents is an error from Angular (not compiler) point of view?